# Sorting CSV file by last name java

Tags: java, csv

I am trying to read a `CSV` file using the `BufferReader` and order the list by last name. When I run the program the array seems to be empty. What am I doing wrong? I saved the file in the source package. I need to write a method to sort by various parameters, but I first want to make sure the file is being read properly and displays. I created a separate class `Record.java` which contains the correct algorithms. Is the error in this file or the other?

```
   private static void readFile() {
       String fileName;
       fileName = "IP4_sample_data.csv";
       System.out.println("Reading " + fileName);
       // Create object of the FileReader
       FileReader reader;
       try
       {
           reader = new FileReader(fileName);    // Reader only connects to specified file name
           BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
           String commaString = null;  // blank at the beginning

           // Reads a complete line
           commaString = bReader.readLine();  

           // If not last line, add to the record
           while((commaString = bReader.readLine())!=null) {
               Record.add(new Record(commaString));
           }
       }

       catch(Exception e)
       {          
           System.out.println("Invalid Filename " + e);
           // readFile();           
       }   
   }

   private static void sortRecordsOnLastName() {
        Collections.sort(records, Record.LastNameComparator());
        System.out.println(records);
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Reading sample_data.csv
Invalid Filename java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
[]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: You have posted way to much code in your question, which makes it unclear to us (and to future readers) exactly where the problem is.  Please reduce your problem code to 10 lines or less.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Don't catch exceptions silently, at least print their error message.

Comment: If `records` comes up empty, then where do you fill it?

Comment: The first line in your file is ignored as it is read before the while loop and read again during the while loop.

Comment: How do I get it to display after the first line?  I seem to be getting a new error

Comment: @BrianB. After you do `// Reads a complete line
           commaString = bReader.readLine(); ` you should just store it after checking that it's not null with `Record.add(new Record(commaString));`